# how to check if value in one list is in another list?

Tags: apex

I am assuming that was asked already but I haven't seen it yet.

I have two lists
listGoalsPrevYears and listGoalsCurrYear

How to check if any values in listGoalsCurrYear is in listGoalsPrevYears?

```
public List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c> listGoalsCurrYear {get;set;}
public List<Community_Plan_Goal_Setting__c> listGoalsPrevYears {get;set;}
```

Comment: Can you [edit] your question to include the formal apex definitions of these objects? Something such as `public List<sObject> someList { get; set; }` would be greatly helpful to this question getting a quality answer.

Comment: I added the definitions

Comment: What criteria are you using to determine if two objects are the same (same ID?, same values in a few fields?) The reason I ask is because a set is probably what you want to use (not a list), but sets don't work well for just a straight comparison of two sObjects

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As far as I know, there is no special way to do this (like `Any` in LINQ).  Assuming you are interested in whether a particular record is in both lists, you can write a method like:

```
public boolean containsAny(List<sObject> toSearch, List<sObject> values)
{
    for (sObject i : values)
    {
        for (sObject j : toSearch)
        {
            if ((ID)j.get('id') == (ID)i.get('id'))
            {
                return true;
            }
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

If you are interested in whether any value in any field on one list is present on the same field in the other list, you could modify the above like:

```
public boolean containsAnyField(List<sObject> toSearch, List<sObject> values)
{
    if (toSearch.size() == 0)
    {
        return false;
    }
    Set<String> fieldList = toSearch[0].getSObjectType().getDescribe().fields.getMap().keySet();
    for (sObject i : values)
    {
        for (sObject j : toSearch)
        {
            for (string k : fieldList)
            {
                if (String.valueOf(i.get(k)) == String.valueOf(j.get(k)))
                {
                    return true;
                }
            }
         }
     }
     return false;
}
```

(I used `String.valueOf` because I think it should return whether or not a value of any type is equivalent to the same value of the same type regardless of the starting type, this has false positives and negatives though, like NaN)